# Separate page node for a specific type of content

Tags: drupal-7

I have atype content "informes"

How I can to create a separate page node for a specific type of content "informes"?

Comment: I do not get what you want to do... do you want to show some of the "informes" (tagged with some mark) different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unable to understand your exact requirement but let me answer what I got.
Create a [panel](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) page and give path to this page for that specific page you want to create for your content type. If you have already created that page using `"/node/add/informes"` then give its link to panel page. hope this is what you want.

Comment: I create a file type node specifically for that type of content "informes" , called " node--informes.tpl.php " The problem is that when I click on some content do not access the new file I create. This file is inside theme->framework also where is the node.tpl.php , also empty cache but still does not work

Comment: ok you must try this      `<?php
function template_name_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
    if (isset($vars['node']->type)) {
        $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][]='page__'.$vars['node']->type;
    }   
}
?>`          and then create page--informes.tpl.php

Comment: inside your template.php file's preprocess_page function.